# TV Show 70s or 80s with futuristic Pickup Truck that pulled huge trailer/train?

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching in the 70s/80s a TV Show with a character Dolph Lundgren like, and the Truck/Train had the front of a kind of Dodge Big Pickup truck that could be separated from the main carriage/trailer. Think he came from the future because he used to hide the truck (kind of like in back to the future). Think there was also another car besides this huge pickup truck/train that the main character had.. Any ideas? Not Highway Man or Ark II... Really bugging me now, would really like to find this out

Comment: Sure sounds an awful lot like The Highway Man. The main guy looked like Dolph Lundgren with dark hair, drove a big futuristic truck, also had a car plus the front of the truck separated into a helicopter. Just sayin'...

Comment: If you're really, really sure it's NOT "The Highway Man", you could be thinking of Goliath from "Knight Rider". Goliath was a big black 18-wheeler that went up against KITT two or three times, both with and without the trailer attached. There was also one episode where KITT was up against BOTH Goliath and the evil KITT called KARR.

Comment: @Omegacron Im really torn with this Highwayman always sounds like the most likely answer and ive seen it over and over again, but i distinctly remember that this pickup truck was something like (http://bestpickuptruck.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/pull-a-trailer-behind-a-fifth-wheel-in-alberta.jpg) but much bigger and i remember thinking that it was amazing how a pickup could pull a huge trailer (similar to an 18 wheeler)...

Comment: Was it something you watched in the US during the 70s/80s? Also, do you remember what color the truck/trailer was?